# Convert strings in text file to array in powershell

Tags: powershell

I think it is easy done, but i can't figure it out at the moment, keep searching.
How can i create an object, hash table or array from a text file. Text file is:

```
FN:Jan Jansen
Email:jj@example.com
FN: Name Two
Email:name@something.co
```

Thanks.
Bluraydisk

Comment: What is your expected output when converted to an object/array/hash table?

Comment: I think you should be more specific in what you want. If you need a hash table, I assume you'd want to parse out the name and key if off the name or something? An array wouldn't care about duplicates, so you have to decide if that's a concern and/or possibility etc.

Comment: When you use get-content with default switches each line is actually part of an array already. It seems like what you are actually wanting here is to turn that into a powershell object. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is if you want to convert your txt file in an hashtable of `name=email`:

```
$a = @()
$b = @{}

,((gc .\myfile.txt -ReadCount 2) ) | % { $a+=$_ }

 $a | % { $b.add( ($_[0] -replace 'FN:').trim() , ($_[1] -replace 'Email:').trim() )}

$b # is the final hastable name=email

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                           
----                           -----                                                                                                                                           
Name Two                       name@something.co                                                                                                                               
Jan Jansen                     jj@example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating objects, using `ConvertFrom-StringData`

```
#Create test file:
(@'
FN:Jan Jansen
Email:jj@example.com
FN: Name Two
Email:name@something.co
'@).split("`n") |   
foreach {$_.trim()} | 
set-content .\testfile.txt

#Code sample using test file:
Get-Content .\testfile.txt -ReadCount 2 |
ForEach-Object {
  New-Object PSObject -Property  ( ConvertFrom-StringData ($_ | Out-String).replace(':','=') )
} | Format-Table -AutoSize


Email             FN        
-----             --        
jj@example.com    Jan Jansen
name@something.co Name Two
```